# How to show shields level by changing color of the progress bar

Tags: python, pygame

I have a progress bar in the code which only shows a GREEN color but i want to modify it with the percentage of a player, if player is between 50 to 100% then its color is GREEN, if it is less than 50 and equal to 25 its color is ORANGE and under 25% is RED color. 
I have attached a python code

I would be very thankful if anybody help

```
def draw_shield_bar(surf, x, y, pct):
```

I have a progress bar in the code which only shows a GREEN color but i want to modify it with the percentage of a player, if player is between 50 to 100% then its color is GREEN, if it is less than 50 and equal to 25 its color is ORANGE and under 25% is RED color. I have attached a python code

I would be very thankful if anybody help

```
def draw_shield_bar(surf, x, y, pct):
    if pct < 0:
       pct = 0
    BAR_LENGTH = 100
    BAR_HEIGHT = 10
    fill = (pct / 100) * BAR_LENGTH
    outline_rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, BAR_LENGTH, BAR_HEIGHT)
    fill_rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, fill, BAR_HEIGHT)
    pygame.draw.rect(surf, GREEN, fill_rect)
    pygame.draw.rect(surf, WHITE, outline_rect, 2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the color dependent on the percentage:

```py
color = GREEN if pct >= 50 else ORANGE if pct >= 25 else RED
pygame.draw.rect(surf, color, fill_rect)
```

---

By the way, the parameters to [`pygame.Rect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) have to be integral, so when you calculate `fill`, then you've to use the integral division operator (`//`), rathet then the floating point division (`/`):

```py
fill = BAR_LENGTH * pct // 100
```

---

[image]

Comment: BAR_LENGTH = 100 

This line of code making the only GREEN to appear. as condition is satisfied with pct >=  50 

How can i add a screenshot here?

Comment: @RizwanAbro `pct` is in range [0, 100], isn't it. So what does `BAR_LENGTH` have to do with it? Do you want to draw a bar with 3 different colors?

Comment: Yes i want to draw a bar with three different colors (only one at a time) 

if the player health percentage is between 50 to 100% the bar color is GREEN. if the player health percentage is between 25 to 49% the bar color is Orange.if the player health percentage is below 25%  the bar color is REd.

Comment: @RizwanAbro *"only one at a time"* - But that is what the code is doing. What is wrong?

Comment: it is just showing GREEN color in my code. i want to modify it with player percentage changing color.